# how do i restart a table's primary key from 0 after deleting rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, primary-key

I have deleted 28 rows from a table. Now, the PK for the table starts at 29. but I want to start from 0 again.

How do I do this?

Comment: You can always drop and re-create the table.  But I think you are worried about something that's not important.

Comment: @DanBracuk There are plenty of reasons why you'd want to reseed the table w/o recreating it.  Recreating indexes for a start.

Comment: Anything else you're missing here Bevan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBCC CheckIdent will reset the table seed.  Choose  like this:

```
GO
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('TableName');
GO
```

You can also set the seed you want to start on:

```
GO
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('TableName', RESEED, 10);
GO
```

[Taken from MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx)